# algoritmo ou raciocínio para obter conjuntos com médias próximas a partir de uma lista

Tags: python, pandas

Tenho a seguinte lista `Cu`, com 40 valores:

```
[1.37812, 1.25154, 1.2486 , 1.22726, 1.22645, 1.16835, 1.14414,
       1.1367 , 1.05915, 1.0446 , 1.03972, 1.03597, 0.98309, 0.94804,
       0.91199, 0.90972, 0.89231, 0.88951, 0.86708, 0.85137, 0.84879,
       0.84476, 0.83314, 0.83251, 0.8125 , 0.79611, 0.78567, 0.78422,
       0.77036, 0.76977, 0.72615, 0.71568, 0.70474, 0.69205, 0.65082,
       0.64072, 0.62434, 0.6147 , 0.56938, 0.56798])
```

Preciso separar essa lista em 10 conjuntos de 4 elementos cada, de forma que as médias dos conjuntos sejam o mais parecido possível entre si.

O que eu tentei foi: mesclar valores altos com valores baixos em todos os conjuntos. Já que a lista está em ordem descendente, criei uma lista `order` para ser o novo índice de cada elemento da lista `Cu`. Essa lista começa com pares em ordem crescente e termina com os ímpares em ordem decrescente. EX> [0,2,4,6,....,36,38,39,37,35,....3,1]

O código para isso é

```
evenArr = []
oddArr = []
order = []
i=0
j=dfbm.shape[0]

for i in range(j):
    if ((i % 2) == 0):
        evenArr.append(i)
    else:
        oddArr.append(i)

evenArr = sorted(evenArr)
oddArr = sorted(oddArr)
oddArr = oddArr[::-1]

order = evenArr + oddArr
```

Depois eu reordenei a lista `Cu` de acordo com o valor de `order` em um `df` o que me deu a seguinte configuração:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Assim, agora eu tenho os maiores e menores valores da lista alternando.

Em seguida, criei uma coluna a mais no `df` chamada `mixture` que dá o mesmo valor para cada 4 linhas e depois usei o `df.groupby['mixture'].mean()` para obter a média de cada grupo, que me deu a seguinte resposta:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O grande objetivo é que a média de cada `mixture` seja a mais parecida possível entre elas. Se a distribuição dos valores da lista `Cu` fosse simétrica, acredito que esse código seria bom, mas como a distribuição é assimétrica positiva, então essa raciocínio não é o melhor.

Penso que a solução esteja em fazer os conjuntos de forma que a média entre os elementos de cada conjunto seja próximo da média da lista `Cu`, que é 0.89.

Alguém poderia me dar uma sugestão de algoritmo ou de raciocínio para esse problema?

Comment: Existe alguma restrição de complexidade? Tendo uma lista com só 40 elementos acredito que um caminho mais _greedy_ acabe servindo o propósito. O que você considera como "médias próximas" ? O quão próximo você precisa que seja?

Comment: O código tem que ser mais generalista, pois deve funcionar para listas com maior ou menor quantidade de elementos. Mas a quantidade máxima nunca passaria de 200-300 elementos. A quantidade de elementos em cada conjunto deve ser um input do usuário também. Quanto à "médias próximas" o ideal seria encontrar a melhor solução possível, mas se isso for computacionalmente muito complexo, ficaria feliz com um codigo que aceitasse limite superior e inferior para esse valores, inputado pelo usuário, para aceitar a solução.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito existirem muitas formas de abordar tal problema. Entretanto, muitas delas envolvem um método iterativo, como por exemplo com a minimização de uma função de custo.

Nesta [pergunta](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31469) podemos ver algumas formas de resolver. Escolhi a que eu achei mais simples, e converti para Python para testes. Ela fornece como saída uma boa aproximação inicial, e não envolve iteração. Acredito que vale a pena conferir as outras formas citadas na pergunta se lhe for necessário:

Basicamente, o algoritmo se resume nos seguintes passos:

- Ordene a lista:

```
Lista_ordenada = cu.sort()
```

- Divida em N sublistas, onde N é o número de elementos que você quer que cada sublista tenha. No seu caso, N = 4, e portanto cada sublista terá 10 elementos:

```
tamanho_das_sublistas = 10
numero_de_sublistas = int(len(cu) / tamanho_das_sublistas)
ListaDasSublistas = [cu[i*tamanho_das_sublistas : ((i+1) * tamanho_das_sublistas)]
                    for i in range(numero_de_sublistas)]
```

- Obtenha a sublista com maior [variância](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vari%C3%A2ncia) e a inverta. Acredito que com uma compreensão de lista dê para diminuir o tamanho dessa parte, mas achei mais legível assim:

```
listaVariancias = [] # Lista onde cada variância é salva
for sublista in ListaDasSublistas:
    media = sum(sublista)/len(sublista)
    variancia = sum((x-media)**2 for x in sublista) / len(sublista)
    listaVariancias.append(variancia)
indiceListaMenorVariancia = listaVariancias.index(max(listaVariancias)) #Obtendo o índice
ListaDasSublistas[indiceListaMenorVariancia].reverse() #Invertendo
```

- Faça a [matriz transposta](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matriz_transposta), obtendo como resposta final 10 listas de 4 elementos cada:

```
solucao = [list(i) for i in zip(*ListaDasSublistas)]
```

Outros métodos de transposição podem ser encontrados [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6473679/10746978). Achei esse o mais simples de entender e sem a necessidade de *imports*.

No seu caso, podemos verificar que as médias foram:

```
medias = [sum(lista)/len(lista) for lista in solucao]
print(medias)

# O que imprime:
[0.89181, 0.86459, 0.8842574999999999, 0.882395, 0.8932500000000001, 0.885915, 0.904185, 0.9144175000000001, 0.9138899999999999, 0.9148149999999999]
```

Que é um resultado com valores bem mais próximos da média informada por você, `0.89`.
A maior distância da média informada pode ser calculada com:

```
print(max([abs(i - 0.89) for i in medias])) # 0.025410000000000044
```

O que é um valor relativamente baixo para uma aproximação inicial: menos de 3% de `0.89`.